# Importance sampling: Why does dividing by average of likelihood ratios also produce an estimator??

Tags: probability-theory

Please read this short snippet on importance sampling, and explain to me why both $F_{3n}$ and $F_{4n}$ are estimators of $F(x)$. I get the first two estimators, but why the last 2?

The context is that we estimate $F(x)$ for some distribution by instead simulating $x_1, ..., x_n$ from a distribution $P'$ with respect to which $F$ is absolutely continuous with density $p(x)$.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klcsc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the last two estimators the denominator is close to 1. Here's why: By construction, the connection between $F$ and the density $p$ is
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x p(t)dP'(t).
$$
Now if $X_i$ has distribution $P'$ then the expectation of $L_i:=p(X_i)$ is
$$
\int p(t)dP'(t) = F(\infty)=1.
$$
So the quantity $\frac1n\sum L_i$ is equal to one on average.